# Cauchy sequences on normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A chauchy sequence on a multiplicative group G with a family of normal subgroups $\{K_n\}$ is defined as a sequence $(g_n)$ of elements of G such that for $m \ge n$:
$K_ng_m=K_ng_n$.

I want to show that the set of cauchy sequences $H$ is a group under componentwise multiplication.

I managed to show everything but the existence of the inverse element $(g_n^{-1})$.

I want to show that for $(g_n)\in H $ it stands $K_n(g_m)^{-1}=K_n(g_n)^{-1}$ with $m \ge n$.
I tried the usuall tricks for normal subgroups but I can't seem to get it right.
Any hints would be great!

Comment: I'm confused... doesn't that show that $(g^{-1}_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, which gives you an inverse?

Comment: yes of course, i edited it so my question is more clear

Comment: I guess I found my answer:   $(K_n(g_m)^{-1})=((g_m)^{-1}K_n)=(K_n(g_m))^{-1}=(K_n(g_n))^{-1}=((g_n)^{-1}K_n)=(K_n(g_n)^{-1})$